# Cabinet containing oven in center of kitchen, possibly load-bearing?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, oven, load-bearing

I bought this house back in 2017 and the layout of the kitchen has driven me mad ever since. I've attempted to look this layout up online but to no avail.
Basically, the cabinet that contains my oven is smack in the middle of kitchen and dining room and closes off the entire area. My question is - and don't worry, I'll have a contractor come out and double check first but - I'm curious if there's anyway that this cabinet could be load-bearing or if there's a possibility of relocating the oven to somewhere else in the kitchen that makes sense?
I won't lie to you, the attached pictures were when I first bought the house (pre 3 disastrous kids living in it) and I've already removed the top cabinets that trace from the wall to the oven. So now the oven cabinet stands alone, only attached to the bar(ish) counter. When you open the top, it's empty and open for storage, in exception to one cable that runs through for the power to the oven. The bottom is also drawer storage.
Any advice or even ideas to make me not hate this are greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: I doubt that an cabinet could be load bearing. But, as a matter of principle, I won't comment anymore on foreign building codes. Anyway: An oven placed higher is all the rage at my location. No need to bend over when looking for the pizza.
Perhaps the entire room would look changed if you place an table and other furniture? The separation between food preparation and dining sounds thoughtful. But tastes are different and difficult to explain.

Comment: It is an odd place to be load bearing, unless a heavy weight(big safe, hot tub) was right above it.  One of the two walls at the steps are probably load bearing, maybe.

Comment: It may or may not be load bearing, but I wouldn't be surprised if the top cabinet you opened up doesn't go all the way to the back, but rather that location is hiding a pipe chase for plumbing drain and supply pipes or other electrical lines that run to your upper level - especially if there are bathrooms above that location.

Comment: That cabinet pillar is very deep. Are there cabinet doors/drawers on the other side, too?

Comment: Measure the depth of the top cupboard, then measure the depth of the whole thing. If the difference is large enough to contain a support, it may. Ofc it could also contain venting. To be sure you could 'explore' inside a cupboard

Comment: I would say it "defines the otherwise vague border between kitchen and dining room" rather than "closing it off" ...tastes vary, since that's not the way you see it, even though you can clearly walk past it.

Comment: It all looks beautiful in the image.